# Jquery - First letter should not be Numeric

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a `textbox` first character should `not be number`. So I have following code for this :-

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4q503ku4/)

```
$('#FieldName').keyup(function (e) {
    if ($(this).val().length === 1 && $.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
        $(this).val('');
        alert('First letter should not be Numeric.!');
    }
});
```

The above code works but not when `typed fast`. Try typing fast numbers in the fiddle. It will accept numbers.

What is solution for this?

Comment: Why do you bind it to keyup? Is that really necessary? Try to think about what you are actually trying to do, what is the logic and user experience you are trying to achieve. Don't just switch it to keydown either, really think about what you want to accomplish with this limitation and how you want it to work - when you have that, you can start to experiment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one. Only takes the first letter of typed text with [slice(0,1):](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) and validates.

```js
    $('#FieldName').keyup(function(e) {
      if ($.isNumeric($(this).val().slice(0, 1))) {
        $(this).val('');
        alert('First letter should not be Numeric.!');
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="FieldName" />
```

Comment: $(this).val()[0]) undefined says . I mentioned slice here because is usefull in many other cases and I like it very much.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution with RegEx

```js
$(function() {
  $('.notFirst').on('input', function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/^(\d+)/, '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="notFirst" />
```

Comment: By far the best solution here, but I really think that the actual need might be more complicated than this, unless this is for a game.

Comment: This is good...But I want an alert to be popped up...or user may think if he is typing numbers first..that why isn't anything happening... :)

Comment: This makes a freaky effect when you keep pressing a number!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#FieldName').keypress(function (e) {
    if ($(this).val().length === 1 && $.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
        $(this).val('');
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('First letter should not be Numeric.!');
    }
});
```

Add e.preventDefault() inside your function.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/b653oo8c/

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem is when the person types fast, I assume it is a performance issue.

To fix it, you can do like this:

```js
$('#FieldName').keydown(function(){
    if(this.value.length==1 && this.value<<0==this.value)
    {
        this.value='';
        alert('First letter should not be Numeric.!');
    }
});
```

Your code should run **AS FAST AS POSSIBLE** inside the event handler!

Using jQuery, you only **slow down** your code.

Not caching `$(this)` slows down **even more**!

I use jQuery just to combat the cross-browser issues, and use the sugested `keydown` event.

One could use this, and would work just fine:

```js
document.getElementById('FieldName').onkeydown=function(){
    if(this.value.length==1 && this.value<<0==this.value)
    {
        this.value='';
        alert('First letter should not be Numeric.!');
    }
}
```

---

According to @Kaiido, it is a problem when checking the length when the `keyup` event fires.

If we keep the performance in sight, we could just get rid of the length check:

```js
document.getElementById('FieldName').onkeydown=function(){
    if(this.value.charAt(0)+1)//if it is a number, it will add 1, making it check as true
    {
        this.value='';
        alert('First letter should not be Numeric.!');
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not a performance issue it's just he's looking for keyup with the condition that `value.length === 1`. Of course if he types fast, when the keyup fires, value is greater than 1 because he already pressed another key.

Comment: It's still a valid point. And if that is the problem, I will adjust the answer.

Comment: @Kaiido I have updated the answer, keeping speed and compatibility in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `keyup()` event to `keydown()`. This should help.

```
$('#FieldName').keydown(function (e) {
  if ($(this).val().length === 1 && $.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
    $(this).val('');
    alert('First letter should not be Numeric.!');
  }
});
```